# JAVA dynamic threading

Tags: java, multithreading

i'm a begginer in java, and i have this code i made, but that t thread gets only executed once, how can i make the thread be dynamic?

//main program - creating 2 threads, unfortuantely at this point only 1 it's running

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    timeThread ttm = new timeThread();
    ttm.name = "map";
    ttm.min = 1000;
    ttm.max = 5000;
    ttm.start();

    timeThread tta = new timeThread();
    tta.name = "arena";
    tta.min = 6000;
    tta.max = 10000;
    tta.start();
}
```

//the timethread i'm calling in the program

```
static class timeThread{
    static String name;
    static int min;
    static int max;
    static int random;
    static Thread t = new Thread () {
        public void run () {
            while (true){
                random = genRandomInteger(min,max);
                System.out.println("Thread named: " 
      + name + " running for: " 
      + random + " secconds...");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(random);
                } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }   
            }
        }
    };
    void start(){
        t.start();
    }
}
```

//the random function generator

```
  private static int genRandomInteger(int aStart, int aEnd){
    int returnValue = aStart + (int)(Math.random() 
* ((aEnd - aStart) + 1));
    return returnValue;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are initializing your thread statically! It means that it is created once when the class is loaded.

Your code does exactly what it is written to do.

You have to modify your `TimeThread` class: remove the static keywords and make the variables class members. Like this:

```
static class TimeThread implements Runnable {
    String name;
    int min;
    int max;
    int random;
    Thread t;

    public void run () {
        while (true){
            random = genRandomInteger(min,max);
            System.out.println("Thread named: " + name + " running for: " 
                               + random + " secconds...");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(random);
            } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }   
        }
    }

    void start(){
        t = new Thread (this);
        t.start();
    }
}
```

Some more hints:

- Put the thread initialization code in a method.
- Do not use anonymous classes, write the `run()` method in `TimeThread` and pass `this` to `Thread` constructor
- use getters and setters, they are considered good practice
- learn more about programming in java... From what I can see in your code, you shuoldn't be touching threads at all.
- your "running for" text actually shows a random number... It really shouldn't.

Comment: i don't know how to make this dynamic `static Thread t = new Thread () {`

Comment: I agree with Dariusz, if you're new to Java stay away from Threads for now. You will probably not find yourself in need of them but if you start with Threads early you'll get into bad habits like sharing resources without properly synchronizing them and so forth. Multithread/concurrent programming is it's own science on top of programming. Work on basic concepts and applications before moving onto something more difficult.